# Prevent sympy from converting sine expression to the equivalent cosine expression

Tags: python, sympy

The original expression

```
sin(x-pi/3)
```

sympy changes this to

```
cos(x+pi/6)
```

Example:

```
fx = sin(x-pi/3)
fn = fx.subs(x,n)
```

Instead of

```
sin(n-pi/3)
```

Sympy returns

```
cos(n+pi/6)
```

How can I prevent sympy from doing this?

Comment: Do you mean `-cos(n+pi/6)`?

Comment: You can use `sin(x-pi/3, evaluate=False)`

Comment: For some reason it didn't work.

Comment: @AndrewMir You tested it and it still returns the cosine result? I tested it and it returned the sine result.